# Pandas data frame saving

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I tried to save pandas dataframe using pickel file it gives memory error. And when I tried with csv and read back it shows very few elements from the list i.e. during save length is of 33000 and when i load it shows only 50.
Is there any way to save dataframe without memory error ?

Comment: Show your code, so that people can see if there are any mistakes in it.

Comment: Saving as csv using  X_cv.to_csv("X_cv.csv") and save as pickle using  X_cv.to_pickle("X_cv.pkl",protocol=1)